# Session Timeout in codeigniter dyanamicly

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have issue regarding codeigniter Timeout .

I know the config folder setting session timeout manually like as  l

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 123;
```

but i need to the website admin manage the session time out dyanamicly in to the admin page

please help me how to implement this logic

i tried this logic but not working

```
$this->session->sess_expiration = "120";
```

Note:here i am storing database in the value. based on the database value i can set in to the session expiration time

note 1: `$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 30;`  this value less than of session expiration time

Total Logic code:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        Assets::add_css('../plugins/forms/uniform/uniform.default.css');
        Assets::add_css('../plugins/forms/select/select2.css');
        Assets::add_css('../plugins/forms/validate/validate.css');
        Assets::add_css('../plugins/misc/qtip/jquery.qtip.css');
        Assets::add_js('../plugins/charts/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js');
        Assets::add_js('../plugins/forms/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js');
        Assets::add_js('../plugins/forms/select/select2.min.js');
        Assets::add_js('../plugins/forms/validate/jquery.validate.min.js');
        Assets::add_js('../plugins/forms/wizard/jquery.bbq.js');
        Assets::add_js('../plugins/forms/wizard/jquery.form.js');
        Assets::add_js('../plugins/forms/wizard/jquery.form.wizard.js');
        Assets::add_module_js('setting','setting'); 
        if ($_POST)
       {
            $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $data = array(
                            's_meta_value' => $this->input->post('s_meta_value'),
                            'updated_on' => $current_date
                          );
            $this->setting_model->session_mng_update($data,$id);
            $session_val=  $this->input->post('s_meta_value');
           if($session_val == 0)
           {
             $this->session->sess_expiration = '0';
           }
           else
           {          

            $this->session->sess_expiration = "120";
          // $val1 = $this->config->item('sess_expiration');
       // print_r($val1);
            //$session_seconds = ($session_val*60);
          $val2 = $this->config->set_item('sess_expiration',50);
          $this->session->CI_Session();
         //$val1=  $this->config->set_item('sess_expiration',50);
            $val3 = $this->config->item('sess_expiration');
             print_r($val3);exit;


           }

            Template::redirect('setting/setting/display');


        } 

       $val3 = $this->config->item('sess_expiration');
        print_r($val3);exit;
        $data = $this->setting_model->session_mng_edit($id);
        Template::set('page_title', 'Edit Session Management');
        Template::set('data', $data);
        Template::set_view('setting/session_management/edit_session_management');
        Template::render();       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could set cookies for this process via `$this->input->set_cookie()`. But if you want to overwrite the config variable then try

```
$this->config->set_item('sess_expiration',120);
```

Also call the session constructor to update the value by

```
$this->session->CI_Session();
```

Comment: it is not working in bonfire codeigniter right now i am using bonfire HMVC of codeigniter

Comment: Nouphal plz refer above code once again i have updated to the code

Comment: What is the ouput of print_r($val3);exit

Comment: just i am debugging here i am identifying the config value set or not

Comment: I got the answer : first config>config.php file comment or remove this //$config['sess_expiration']  = 7200; //  this sess expertime logic written in the config/application folder you will go to the config >appliction.php folder to do like this require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );

$query = DB()->select('s_meta_value');
$query = DB()->get('lr_settings_meta');
$res=$query->result();
$ideal_time=$res[0]->s_meta_value;
   if($ideal_time)
 {
  $session_seconds = ($ideal_time*60);
  $config['sess_expiration']  = "$session_seconds";
 }
 else
 {
  $config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;
 }

Comment: If this worked for u, then please try to explain what mistakes u made so that readers can benefit from it

Comment: i was implemented new logic config->application file i was written my session time out logic it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
$remember_me = $this->input->post('remember_me');
if ($remember_me == 'remember_me')
{
    //set session to non-expiring
    $this->session->sess_expiration = '32140800'; //~ one year
    $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = 'false';
    #$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
}
else
{
    //set session expire time, after that user should login again
    $this->session->sess_expiration = '1800'; //30 Minutes
    $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = 'true';
    #$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
}

//set session and go to Dashboard or Admin Page
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
    'id' => $result[0]['id'],
    'username' => $result[0]['username']
));
```